# Getting a variable from a url in mvc from another controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, variables

In MVC 4 I'm trying to access a variable from a view that is not the view of the controller.  I'm sending across a single variable in the url:

```
?variable=value
```

and need to get that variable from a controller that is not the controller of the view.

I'm querying the database from another controller and using IEnumerable and sending that data to the controller of the view where the variable is coming from.

Hopefully this makes sense.  How do get that variable?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you add more details ?

Comment: Need More clarity in your question...we are not getting ur question

Comment: do you want to pass value from one controller to another controller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I simply added (string Variable) to the action method of the controller I needed to grab the variable from as well as added it to the controller of the view and it get's the variable:

```
public IEnumerable<dynamic> Execute(string variable)
{
}
```

and

```
public ActionResult Index(string variable)
{
return View()
}
```

Sorry for the confusion.